# How to use an input varibale value as a parameter to an input command in inno setup

Tags: parameters, input

I am new to Inno Setup tool.I have designed a custom page using Inno setup which contains three text boxes.Once the user entered the values in the text boxes i want to pass these values as parameters to a cmd file which i will run in the RUN block.

Can anyone help me in this.

Regards,
Rajesh

Comment: can anyone give me some suggestions like can we pass parameters as string values that we got in the code section or not?is it possible with inno setup or not